# Create security connection

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, mq

I have win service  that work with MQ.

But i want that it works using ssl channel and database with public/private keys(for that)

May you explain me how to do it.

P.S. I'm not very good at MQ

now i connect to MQ using this code

```
                        MQEnvironment.Hostname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostnameIN"];
                        MQEnvironment.Channel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelIN"];
                        MQEnvironment.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortIN"]);
                        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCCSID", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQCCSID"]);
                        var mqQueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManagerNameIN"];
                        var mqQueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueNameIN"];
                        const int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_BROWSE | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
                        var qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqQueueManagerName);
                        var getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
```

and get all  messages  using this

```
using (var mqQueue = qMgr.AccessQueue(mqQueueName, openOptions))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                //while (mqQueue.CurrentDepth>0)
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    var message = new MQMessage();
                                    //message.Version = 2;
                                    getOptions.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
                                    mqQueue.Get(message, getOptions);
                                    mqMessages.Add(message);
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to set up MQ to use SSL on the channel you're using, you don't need to make any application changes at all - you simply need to configure the channel you're using on the queue manager to require SSL. The libraries within the client, JVM, and the queue manager will handle establishing that secure connection for you. So in theory all you need to do is make the MQSC/MQ Explorer changes which will configure SSL on the channel.

Recommend you read the following page in the IBM knowledge center. It provides a number of scenarios for various methods of connecting a client securely to the queue manager:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q014220_.htm